# My func has lots of "if", how can i build a loop to fix it?

Tags: swift

like this, I have no build a model for it, so it has lots of "if", and how can I build a loop to fix it?

```
    @State var player1show = true
    @State var player2show = true
    @State var player3show = true
    @State var player4show = true

func closeall() {
        if !player1show{
            player1show.toggle()
            player1.stop()
        }
        if !player2show{
            player2show.toggle()
            player2.stop()
        }
        if !player3show{
            player3show.toggle()
            player3.stop()
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You have not provided enough details to tell why your code is structured how it is, but I can guess that it’s a pattern I see often when teaching programming. Instead of having things like `player2show`, make an array called `playershow` or something so that you can do `for i in 0..<numberOfPlayers { if !playershow[i] { ... } }`.

Comment: @deaton.dg Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "player" is an instance of class Player which has a property "show" (or method) and the methods toggle() and stop(). Maybe have a base class and virtual overridable methods for this. This is not a must, but having a base class for all players is good OOP practice, so you can specify more every single player type.
2. "players" is an array or list of all active players in the game. You must maintain this list.

   ```
    for player in players
    {
       if !player.show
       {
          player.toggle()
          player.stop()
       }
    }
   ```

Hope this gives you an idea!

Comment: Don't need a base class for this, a protocol would suffice.